# Check / Uncheck a ToggleButton From a StoryBoard in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, togglebutton

I have an animation that expand / collapse some `StackPanel`s, in the window there are some `ToggleButton`s that must be unchecked when the `StackPanel` is collapsed. I have the animation like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="cmdUnchecked">
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
      <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="37"/>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

This hides the `StackPanel`, but I need to uncheck the T`oggleButton` from other events.

Is it possible to uncheck the `ToggleButton` From this `StoryBoard`?

An if so, do I need to verify if it's already checked / unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames like so:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="YourToggleButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

You should not need to check if it's already checked since setting it to false when it's already false should have no side effects.

Comment: When the ToggleButton is Unchecked it doesn't do anything, and when is checked throws an error "Can not animate property 'IsChecked' on 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton' with 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames'" Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BooleanAnimations` to animate Boolean values:

```
     <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="YourToggleButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
           <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
     </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

You can put your `DoubleAnimations` in `ToggleButton.Triggers` as `EventTriggers` on `RoutedEvents` `Checked` and `Unckecked`, then just check/unckeck the toggle button with `BooleanAnimation` and `ToggleButton` will automatically run the double animations to change height of stackpanel